# when ever i am trying to start a project after i have installed django, execution displays No Module Found Error :django module or django.core

Tags: python, django, cmd

```
(.env) C:\Users\shara\Desktop\testfolder\_djhole>pip install Django (executed)
(.env) C:\Users\shara\Desktop\testfolder\_djhole>django-admin start project my site (No Module Found Error)
```

I have repeated this process for a long time. Cannot start working on Django so far due to this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'; 'Django' is not a package
```

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it several times. when I use pip freeze then

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.7
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

But still cannot start working on Django because the module is not found an error.

By the way, there is only one python version 3.8.3 and added to the path. I hope that there would be some genius out there who could give me some answer because I have searched all over the internet for resolving this diabolical problem and got no company.

Comment: Try using `python -m` so that you're definitely using the correct environment, i.e. `python -m pip install django`, `python -m pip freeze` to double check it's installed, and then `python -m django startproject mysite` to create the project

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have such an environment for your current project, then you need to do this

```
mkvirtualenv .env
```

You either already have an environment or just created it. Then you need to use the virtual environment. You can do that with this:

```
workon .env
```

Check if there is a requirements.txt file in the root of your project. If there is, then it means someone (perhaps you), has created a file which lists all of the packages that have to be installed to get it up and running. If that’s the case, then you only need to run this:

```
pip install -R requirements.txt
```

If you don’t have a requirements.txt files, then just run this:

```
pip install django
```

This will install the latest version of Django. If you need a specific version, then you can do that as well with:

```
pip install django==2.2.4
```